# How to force the expression to have common denominator?

Tags: functions, syntax

Suppose there are two (or more) functions with inequivalent denominators, say `f1[x] = F[x]/G[x], f2[x] = f[x]/g[x]`. How in general to force the sum `f1[x]+f2[x]` of these functions be calculated with the common denominator?

Comment: Would you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : the example which I have is so long...

Comment: `Factor[f1[x] + f2[x]]` gives `(F[x] g[x] + f[x] G[x])/(g[x] G[x])`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Have you seen `Together[]`?

Comment: @aardvark2012 : thank you!

Comment: @JohnTaylor `Together` (from @J.M. and @eldo) was what I was trying to think of. `Factor` probably isn't the thing to use here.

Comment: When I entered "common denominator" (without quotes) in the documentation center, `Together` was the second hit. So this one in not exactly well hidden in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f1 = F[x]/G[x];

f2 = f[x]/g[x];

Together[f1 + f2]
```

[image]

To tear it apart again

```
Apart @ Together[f1 + f2]
```

[image]

```
List @@ %
```

[image]